# YouTube download

Tags: java, youtube

Здравствуйте! Возможно, этот вопрос тут задавали, но я не нашёл (также гугл тоже отнекивается). Суть вот в чем:
как достать ссылку на скачивание видео с YouTube? Столько сервисов есть,  которые качают видео,  но никто не даёт API.
Заранее всем спасибо за ответ!

Comment: У ютуба есть, вроде, апи

Comment: API есть но там точно нет ссылки на скачивание )

Comment: @ЮрийСПб покажите где там ссылка -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите, как это сделано в [java YouTube video Downloader (ytd2)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ytd2/), например.

Comment: Ух ты, спасибо. Вот, самый сок :)

Answer (score 1):

Для скачивания видео, по-моему, API нет (это идёт в разрез с их [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms)) — поэтому, например, [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py) первым делом выкачивает веб-страницу, а затем уже достаёт оттуда ссылку. Как вариант, можно изучить его алгоритм и перенести его на Java.

Comment: Благодарю! Буду смотреть. Насчёт апи я имел ввиду сторонних сайтов. Но нет,  все жадничают :)